# Game State Management using Lua

Tags: c++, scripting, state, lua

I want to be able to (only) define game states using Lua script, but I'm not sure how I should do it. Here's what I have in mind currently:

For each state, I will create a .lua file that contains a class (table) that has the same name as the file name. Each table must have a set of event handlers: onEnter (called when the state is entered), onUpdate (called every frame) and onExit (called when exiting the state). So if I want to have a MainMenuState, I will have a file called "MainMenuState.lua" which will contain something like this:

```
MainMenuState = {}

MainMenuState["onEnter"] = function()
end

MainMenuState["onUpdate"] = function(elapsedTime)
end

MainMenuState["onExit"] = function()
end
```

Defined states will be exposed to the game engine via a singleton StateManager class. StateManager will have a function that registers a state under a unique name:

```
void registerState(string stateName, string fileName);
```

State registration will be done in script by placing the registration codes inside an init script that is called once after the game engine is initialized:

```
--init.lua
--Register all the states needed by the game
StateManager:registerState("SplashScreen", "SplashScreen.lua")
StateManager:registerState("MainMenuState", "MainMenuState.lua")
StateManager:registerState("InGameState", "InGameState.lua")
-- etc etc
```

StateManager will also keep track of which state is currently active and also handle state transitions:

```
//cpp
void changeState(string state);

--lua
StateManager:changeState("PauseMenuState")
```

Comment: may ask what is your problem? every thing looks just fine. I can only add OnRender event to your state system to make it more complete.

Comment: There's no problem (yet). This is my first time using scripting for a project, and I'm just wondering if my hypothetical approach is good enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but there's nothing inherently "wrong" with the way you are structuring your state machine. As long as it fits the task at hand, any implementation can be considered "correct".

One change I would suggest making is to allow the states themselves to be instanced, so that you can store state in your instance. This can be as simple as:

```
SplashScreen = {}
local instance = setmetatable({}, SplashScreen)

SplashScreen.createInstance = function(...)
    local instance = setmetatable({}, SplashScreen)
    instance.endTime = 5.0 -- set instance data
    return instance
end

function SplashScreen:update(elapsedTime)
    if elapsedTime > self.endTime then -- use instance data
        changeState('MainMenuState')
    end
end
```

Note that, due to the `setmetatable` call, `instance` tracks all of your state's functions; so your 'current state' is really just an `instance` ref in your `StateManager`:

```
function StateManager:changeState(stateName, ...)
    local stateTable = --[[ get state from file ]]
    local instance = stateTable.createInstance(...)

    self.currentState = instance
end

function StateManager:call(funcName, ...)
    local fn = self.currentState[funcName]
    fn(self.currentState, ...)
end
```

Answer (score -2):

I preferred to use numbers with my state systems. It's not the best way but it works great for me.

```
state = 1
while true do
    if state==1 then
       if 1=1 then
          state=2
       end
    end
    if state==2 then
        if 2=2 then
          state=1
        end 
    end
end
```

works for me :)

Comment: This is a horrible horrible way of dealing with states, don't do it people!

Comment: Why is it 2xhorrible?

Comment: @RichardSparrow Because you always need to know what each number means. If anyone else were to work on the code, or if you were to go back to try to fix a bug a few weeks or months after writing it, `if state==1` would be a mystery